# How can I stop Google Play Music from automatically downloading my library?

Tags: google-play-music

I listened to some of my music library on Google Play for the first time, and unbeknownst to me, it started to download the whole library (12,00 plus tracks) to my phone, completely using up my storage. I can't find ANYTHING that allows me to stop it or limit it's downloading. Has anyone else had similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Google Play Music app Touch Menu on your device and see if Keep on device is checked. If yes uncheck it. You can also touch the blue pin to stop making it available offline. For more information on this go to https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1250232?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I found this article below that was helpful for cleaning up what I didn't want and keeping the free music that I did want. Instructions:

- Select "Free and Purchased" in the left side menu (or where ever the menu is, google may change this tomorrow :P )
- You can then use shift-click to select multiple items.
  (Shift-click: Hold shift down and then click the top song to delete, scroll to the bottom and hold shift again and click the last song you want to delete.)

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/E3mRmjLwMjk/SfYzCXb33WwJ